# Dependent dropdownlist works fine in increasing order selected in first dropdownlist but fails in decreasing order

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm new to Jquery. I have written a dependent dropdownlist where I select a value from first dropdownlist and all the values greater than the first dropdownlist gets displayed in second dropdownlist.
When I select a value in first dropdownlist the below function gets called :

```
<script>    
function cost_change(price) {
    var value = price;
    console.log("value",value);      
    var toKeep = jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select option').filter( function( ) {
        return parseInt(this.value) > parseInt( value);       
 } );        
   console.log("to keep",toKeep);
   jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html(toKeep);
}
</script>
```

Now, the function works fine but problem is, 
For the first time I selected 3 from first dropdownlist then, in second dropdownlist values [4,5,6] were displayed.
After that I selected 2 from first dropdownlist then, in second dropdownlist values [4,5,6] were displayed instead of [3,4,5,6].
The values displayed when I select numbers in increasing order in first dropdownlist works fine. But when I decrease the value in first dropdownlist less than the previously selected value there is no change.

Is it  a problem with cache or the above function has to be modified.

**EDIT :**
variable price passed to the function cost_change is the value selected in first dropdownlist and works fine

**HTML :**

```
<td width="250" bgcolor="#F1F5F6">
                        <select id="SearchForm_min_cost_select" style="display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>

</select><input type="text" id="SearchForm_min_cost" name="SearchForm[min_cost]" style="width:70px" placeholder="Min Cost" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"><button type="button" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" id="btn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span></button>        <select id="SearchForm_max_cost_select" style="display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select><input type="text" id="SearchForm_max_cost" name="SearchForm[max_cost]" style="width:70px" placeholder="Max Cost" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"><button type="button" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" id="btn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span></button>                            </td>
```

Comment: can you show your html here? or make a fiddle?

Comment: @nrsharma I have posted it

Comment: where you are calling "cost_change(price)"?

Comment: @nrsharma I'm using a Yii widget.          $this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'min_cost',
                    'data' => Yii::app()->params['cost_min_resales'],
                    
                    'options' => array(
          'onSelect' => 'cost_change(item.value);',
                        'allowText' => false,
                    ),
                    
                    'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Min Cost', 'style'=>'width:70px'),
                ));

Comment: @nrsharma Please suggest me what I should do for this

Comment: see my answer posted below ;

Comment: @nrsharma Yesit works but, when 6 is selected in first dropdownlist, then no options are shown in second dropdownlist. How can I change this to 6 without empty

Comment: because the condition will be false in this case as there isn't any value > 6 so it will be empty

Comment: Thats working absolutely fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is "The options in the second dropdown gets redrawn when you filter it first time so when you try to do it again there isn't more options to match the condition".

you need to rebind the second dropdown when doing filter on it

```
$('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html($('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').html())
```

Have a look here, it will work for you

```
function cost_change(price) {
    var value = price;
    console.log("value",value);     
    $('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html($('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').html());
    var toKeep = jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select option').filter( function( ) {
        return parseInt(this.value) > parseInt( value);       
 } );        
   console.log("to keep",toKeep);
   jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html(toKeep);
}
```

And here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aMcrH/)